# SQL Developer Lost all Connections

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to oracle database using SQL Developer. For the last 2 years I never had any issues but all of a sudden, all connections were lost. I tried to add new a one, and the connection is testing successfully. But when I clicked on the Connect button nothing happens.

I tried updating the java version to latest one, but the problem still persists.

What could be the issue? Is it related to Firewall?

Comment: Is there such a thing as Connection Pools and Connection Limits in Oracle?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to assist you in Editing your question and adding more information